# Non-specific career goals

Tags: career-development

I am currently seeking a position. I just graduated with a BA in communications and I have 3-5 years of professional work history. I am conflicted when potential employers ask me "what are you looking to do" because I have no idea. I am just looking for something that will be a good fit and will be able to use my skills. How do I respond to these questions?

Comment: Do you do any kind of research of the companies you are to interview with before you show up for interviews? If your mind goes blank when they ask you "why do do you want to work for us?" because you can't think of one thing to say, then it's a bad sign.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with being unsure of what you want to do at the beginning of your career.  When answering this type of question, there's no need to be too specific, especially in your situation.

> I am just looking for something that will be a good fit and will be able to use my skills

What do you see as your skills?   Maybe you're a people person.  Maybe you're extremely organized.  Maybe you're very creative.  Maybe you're a natural leader. Whatever your skills are, you need to think about how they relate to this job opportunity and phrase your answer accordingly.

For example, I'm fairly creative and enjoy big-picture work.  I'm not really a "details" person.  So my response in your situation might be to say "I'm looking for a position that can take advantage of my creativity and my skills in long-term planning.  I'm open to any role where these skills would be valuable to the business."

So, in summary:

1. Think about the intersection between the requirements of the job and
   what you're good at.  Pitch your skills accordingly.  If there isn't much of an intersection, the job may not be for you.
2. When answering questions like this one, try to
       focus on how you can benefit the
       organization and not the other way around.  You want the hiring
       manager to see what you have to offer and to think about how you can
       contribute.

Comment: This is a much better answer than what I gave, and I endorse it.